# UIScrollView not working with any components in xcode 4.5 ios 6.0

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have tried with `UIScrollView` contains `UITextfield` and other components. It's been worked without contains any compenents(`UITextfield`) but it's not working even I simply place any components on it.

I just tried with this code and mapped scrollview property with `UIScrollview` UI component.

Can anybody help me to get off from this issue.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear
{
.....
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(320, 830)];
....
}
```

Comment: put u r question some more clearly....

Comment: its problem of xcode 4.5. me too facing the problem.
so shifted back to xcode 4.4

Comment: UIScrollview not working on ios6. If I place any component on scrollview like (UITextfield or UImage) and try to run the program. Scrollview is not working. Is there any different in implementation between 4.3 and 4.5. Since It's working perfectly xcode 4.3.

Comment: The contents isn't scrolling while you move the scroll up and down.

Comment: Hi Guys I found the solution after a long head bang. Please select and right click on your .xib file ->Open AS Source Code -> find <bool key="IBDocument.UseAutolayout">YES</bool>. Make it NO instead of YES. then save,build and run your app. I'm sure it will work. If it's not just quit your xcode and reopen it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to uncheck Use Autolayout, I also need to change the size under simulated metrics from Retina 4 Full Screen to None to make it work.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I'm not able to file any attribute as Autolayout on the right side bar. could you please give me some light on this ?